# Selecionar registo da base de dados para variável

Tags: mysql, array, linux, bash, revisão-de-código

O código em baixo visa selecionar um registo da base de dados e guardar o mesmo numa variável para posterior utilização dos dados:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

dbName='basedados'
dbUser='utilizador'
dbPass='password'

row=$(echo "select file_id, file from catalogue__pdf_file WHERE is_converted='no' ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT 0,1" | mysql $dbName -u $dbUser --password=$dbPass)

arr=($row)
```

O código em cima seleciona um registo e passa o mesmo para a variável `row` que fica da seguinte forma:

```sh
echo $row
# Saída: file_id file 29 ficheiro.jpg
```

Depois, ao passar o valor da variável `row` para uma matriz via `arr=($row)`:

```sh
echo ${arr[3]}
# Saída: ficheiro.jpg
```

## Pergunta

Para o que foi descrito, o processo está a decorrer de forma eficiente ou o mesmo pode ser simplificado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o objectivo que descreves está correcto. Podes no entanto fazer uma pequena alteração, removendo a utilização do `echo`, caso estejas a usar uma versão suficientemente actual da shell bash que suporte ["here strings"](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)

```
row=$(mysql $dbName -u $dbUser --password=$dbPass <<< "select file_id, file from catalogue__pdf_file WHERE is_converted='no' ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT 0,1")
```

Deixo apenas uma sugestão no que diz respeito aos dados **dbName, dbUtilizador, dbPass**. Normalmente o que eu faço é guardar esta informação num ficheiro de configuração, ao invés de incluir esta informação no script onde executas o comando. Isto pode ser útil caso, no futuro, tenhas vários scripts que usam as mesmas credenciais e necessites de fazer uma alteração. Desta forma apenas alteras o teu ficheiro de configuração e não um conjunto de scripts individualmente.

Eu guardo os dados no ficheiro `~/.my.cnf` com a estrutura.

```
[client]
user = 'utilizador'
password = 'password'
database= 'basedados'
```

Desta forma o teu comando ficaria:

```
row=$(mysql <<< "select file_id, file from catalogue__pdf_file WHERE is_converted='no' ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT 0,1")
```

Caso o script seja usado por mais que um utilizador, podes centralizar esta informação num directório comum e que os vários utilizadores tenham accesso e usar a [flag](http://4.2.3.4.%20Command-Line%20Options%20that%20Affect%20Option-File%20Handling) `--defaults-file=/path1/path2/ficheiro_configuracao` no teu script para indicar a sua localização.

O teu comando ficaria:

```
row=$(mysql --defaults-file=/path1/path2/ficheiro_configuracao <<< "select file_id, file from catalogue__pdf_file WHERE is_converted='no' ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT 0,1")
```